How to change style of ref <Fab/> mui?
I need to change the style of the fab where I click on the fab.
I try to styled with fabRef.current.style.left = 10
but I get error

Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'left').

this is the code:
const fabRef = useRef(null);

const handleClick = () => {
  if (fabRef.current) fabRef.current.style.left = leftHover + "px";
  debouncedOnPlayIdxSelected(gotoIdx, gotoTimeHover);
  setMode("pending");
  setGotoTime(gotoTimeHover);
};
return (
  <Fab
    ref={fabRef}
    onMouseDown={(event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      setDraggable(true);
    }}
    size="small"
    color="primary"
    style={{
      zIndex: 2147483647,
      background: "#b60202",
      position: "absolute",
      top: 22,
      left: document.body.clientWidth * 0.05 - 22,
    }}
  >
    <span />
  </Fab>
);

